# Handling quotes and special characters with PDO

Tags: pdo

How can I escape user inputs of apostrophe and such using PDO? I have a form that inserts with PDO and the form has a text input where a user can enter a title for something. If they type something like "Don't know yet" the title shows up as "Don\'t know yet". I used to handles this with mysql_real_escape_string, but not sure how to handle it using PDO? Is there some function or keyword I add to my PDO insert code to handle these special characters users enter and strip out the "\" that php/mysql adds?

I am using prepared statements and binding eveything so I'm not worried about security. I just want the user text to display properly on the pages.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have "magic quotes" enabled. So either in your php.ini or using `ini_set` set all of the following to `off`:

- magic_quotes_gpc
- magic_quotes_runtime
- magic_quotes_sybase

If that doesn't help, search for `addslashes()` call somewhere in your code that processes user input.
PDO doesn't add such things itself.

Comment: I am using WordPress so is it best to leave that stuff on and use magic_quotes, or is that insecure or just not something I can use inside of PDO statements?

Comment: Magic quotes are not insecure. It was a very old technique that pretended to increase security, but it's suggested to turn this off nowadays. So please set all of these to `off` and try again.